# SQL - Return dataset pivoted on one column with multiple aggregates

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

Using TSQL 2012 here, essentially I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
Period    Values    OtherValues SiteName    MoreColumns
1          12            45      Site 1         34
2          34            6       Site 1         346
2          56            79      Site 1         345
3          3             78      Site 1         67
3          4             67      Site 1         8
```

What I would like to return is a dataset that groups on site and sums all the other columns based on the period they're against.

```
Site    P1V       P2v    P3V    P1OtherV    P2OtherV    P3OtherV
Site 1    12      90      7       45          85          145
```

I know I can do it with a case in the style of:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Period = '1' THEN Sum(Values) As P1Values,
       CASE WHEN Period = '2' THEN Sum(Values) As P2Values,
       CASE WHEN Period = '3' THEN Sum(Values) As P3Values
       .....
```

But surely there's a more elegant solution for this? The dataset should return three sums (for each period) for 7 columns, so in total 21 sums, with the potential to grow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use UNPIVOT/PIVOT sequence:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT Period+Col Period, SiteName, Value FROM
    Src UNPIVOT (Value FOR Col IN (SapValues,OtherValues)) U
) U
PIVOT (SUM(Value) FOR Period IN (P1SapValues,P2SapValues,P3SapValues,
                                 P1OtherValues,P2OtherValues,P3OtherValues)) P
```

Comment: Excellent. Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) and making source table with UNION

```
WITH T1 AS 
(
   SELECT Period + 'SapValues' as Period, SapValues as Value, SiteName FROM T
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Period + 'OtherValues' as Period, OtherValues as Value, SiteName FROM T
)

SELECT *
FROM T1
PIVOT
(
Sum(Value)
FOR Period IN ([P1SapValues],[P2SapValues],[P3SapValues],
               [P1OtherValues],[P2OtherValues],[P3OtherValues])
) AS PivotTable;
```